# Compare Javascript Ajax Response with String

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to compare the result from from ajax call with a string. My result is returning the correct result but i can't get the if statement to compare this with my string, any ideas?

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sessionCheck.php",
        data: {id:mwdata},
        success: function(html) {
            if (html == "open"){
                alert ("yes it's open");   
            }else if(html == "closed"){
                alert ("no it's closed");   
            }  
        }
      });
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error? What do you see when you add `console.log(html)`?

Comment: Odds are that `html` contains whitespace you aren't accounting for. Use JSON instead of invalid HTML.

Comment: I don't get any errors and the console.log just confirms i'm getting the result of either open or closed

Comment: Are you sure there is no whitespace in your response? Run the code: `console.log(html.length);` and see the length is correct

Comment: Another way is to add this code: `else { alert("it is not close neither open"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was to trim the result var result = $.trim(html);